# How to show webcam video stream into Picturebox using OpenCVSharp in winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, opencv

I am using this class to record webcam videos successfully. But the problem with this code is, i am unable to show the live video into the picturebox

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;
using Size = OpenCvSharp.Size;

namespace Video_capture_23_08_2022
{
    public class Recorder : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly VideoCaptureAPIs _videoCaptureApi = VideoCaptureAPIs.DSHOW;
        private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _threadStopEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        private readonly VideoCapture _videoCapture;
        private VideoWriter _videoWriter;

        private Mat _capturedFrame = new Mat();
        private Thread _captureThread;
        private Thread _writerThread;
        //private OutputArray frame;

        private bool IsVideoCaptureValid => _videoCapture is not null && _videoCapture.IsOpened();

        public Recorder(int deviceIndex, int frameWidth, int frameHeight, double fps, PictureBox pictureBox)
        {
            _videoCapture = VideoCapture.FromCamera(deviceIndex, _videoCaptureApi);
            _videoCapture.Open(deviceIndex, _videoCaptureApi);

            _videoCapture.FrameWidth = frameWidth;
            _videoCapture.FrameHeight = frameHeight;
            _videoCapture.Fps = fps;

             // Custom Function to show the webcam view into picturebox  
            _videoCapture.Read(_capturedFrame);
            if (!(_capturedFrame.Empty()))
            { 
            pictureBox.Image = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(_capturedFrame);

            }

        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            Dispose(true);
        }

        ~Recorder()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                StopRecording();

                _videoCapture?.Release();
                _videoCapture?.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void StartRecording(string path)
        {
            if (_writerThread is not null)
                return;

            if (!IsVideoCaptureValid)
                ThrowHelper.ThrowVideoCaptureNotReadyException();

            _videoWriter = new VideoWriter(path, FourCC.XVID, _videoCapture.Fps, new Size(_videoCapture.FrameWidth, _videoCapture.FrameHeight));

            _threadStopEvent.Reset();

            _captureThread = new Thread(CaptureFrameLoop);
            _captureThread.Start();

            _writerThread = new Thread(AddCameraFrameToRecordingThread);
            _writerThread.Start();
        }

        public void StopRecording()
        {
            _threadStopEvent.Set();

            _writerThread?.Join();
            _writerThread = null;

            _captureThread?.Join();
            _captureThread = null;

            _threadStopEvent.Reset();

            _videoWriter?.Release();
            _videoWriter?.Dispose();
            _videoWriter = null;
        }

        private void CaptureFrameLoop()
        {
            while (!_threadStopEvent.Wait(0))
            {
                _videoCapture.Read(_capturedFrame);
            }
        }

        private void AddCameraFrameToRecordingThread()
        {
            var waitTimeBetweenFrames = 1_000 / _videoCapture.Fps;
            var lastWrite = DateTime.Now;

            while (!_threadStopEvent.Wait(0))
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastWrite).TotalMilliseconds < waitTimeBetweenFrames)
                    continue;
                lastWrite = DateTime.Now;
                _videoWriter.Write(_capturedFrame);
            }
        }

        public Bitmap GetFrameBitmap()
        {
            if (!IsVideoCaptureValid)
                ThrowHelper.ThrowVideoCaptureNotReadyException();

            using (Mat frame = new Mat())
                return !_videoCapture.Read(frame) ? null : frame.ToBitmap();
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to modify it a bit to show the webcam view into the picturebox but this custom section

```
 // Custom Function to show the webcam view into picturebox  
 _videoCapture.Read(_capturedFrame);
 if (!(_capturedFrame.Empty()))
  { 
   pictureBox.Image = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(_capturedFrame); 
  }
```

is only showing a still image instead of a live video.
Kindly help me to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing part in your implementation is that you capture the webcam image and display it in `pictureBox` in the constructor, only once rather than in `CaptureFrameLoop()`, repeatedly. Therefore, you need to move this block to `CaptureFrameLoop()`.

```
_videoCapture.Read(_capturedFrame);
if (!(_capturedFrame.Empty()))
{ 
   pictureBox.Image = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(_capturedFrame); 
}
```

Also, you should use `Control.Invoke` to modify the image of the `PictureBox` from a non-UI thread.

```
private void CaptureFrameLoop()
{
   while (!_threadStopEvent.Wait(0))
   {
        _videoCapture.Read(_capturedFrame);
        if (!(_capturedFrame.Empty()))
        { 
            pictureBox.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox.Image = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(_capturedFrame))); 
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it is giving a Delegate Error `Cannot Convert the lambda expression to type Delegate because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: Forgot to mention that I used .Net 6 C# 10. You can use `new Action(() => pictureBox.Image = 
            OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(_capturedFrame))`.

Comment: `new Action()` has fixed the error message but my app now went to the background process,  if I remove this block of code, it works fine. I am initializing the `recorder` object in the `Form Load` method

Comment: What does *my app went to the background process* mean? It doesn't kill?

Comment: I mean my app or winform form is not visible now, I can know that the app is running in the background because the light of the webcam is on(Recorder class is accessing the webcam) to kill the app I have to open the task manager and kill the process. If I remove this specific section of the code everything works fine.

Comment: You should open a new question for this new issue. I provided the answer for this question and it is not proper to mix another problem and its answer on this thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248577/discussion-between-farhan-basheer-and-jtxkopt).